# Julia: check if a vector is a vector of numbers

Tags: if-statement, types, julia

I'd like to check if my vector / array is made of numbers.

I've tried:

```
if isa(x, Array{Number})
  println("yes")
end
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Please, whenever you post a question like this, please be explicit about "what doesn't work". E.g. say what error you get, or better yet, write a minimal standalone example. Otherwise it tends to lead to a lot of guesswork (or, typically, to negative votes and no answers).

Comment: E.g., `x = Array{Number}([1,2,3,4]); x isa Array{Number}` does work. Which, given the accepted answer, is __not__ what you were asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two scenarios here.

Scenario 1. You want to check if type of a vector allows only numbers. Then write:

```
eltype(x) <: Number
```

Scenario 2. You want to check if actually all elements of a vector are numbers. Then write:

```
all(isa.(x, Number))
```

The second is less efficient because it has to check the whole array. The reason why it might be sometimes needed is that you can have e.g.:

```
x = Any[1, 2, 3]
```

which contains only numbers, but type of the vector in general allows it to contain other things than numbers (so it will fail scenario 1 but pass scenario 2).

Comment: just adding that `x isa Array{<:Number}` also works for the first scenario, as it's closer to the wording of the question